# How to find ID in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

Hi i have this script which i really want to get the auth user ID when logged in. When logged in i want that the users id and only from the addrecords table will only display. Here is my code below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Addrecord;
use App\User;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(){
        $ids = Auth::User()->id;
        echo $ids; 
        $datas = Addrecord::all()->toArray();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($datas);
        echo "</pre>"; 

        return view('home', compact('datas'));
    }
}
```

I want this line of code here

```
$datas = Addrecord::all()->toArray();
```

that line of code really works but i want that only user id from the table addrecord will only be displayed. Not all will be displayed but only the loggedIn user.

Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Try this `$datas = Addrecord::where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->get();` !! assuming that you have a column `user_id` in the Addrecord table :)

Comment: Yes i have a user_id in Addrecord table :) okay ill try your code thank you

Comment: Is it working for your case ??

Comment: hmmm no its not working

Comment: wait. ill double check hang on!

Comment: yeah!!! thanks for the help its working now :) Awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query like this:

```
$datas = Addrecord::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

Comment: this is the output when i print_r on it 
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
)

Comment: @PHPDev use 'user_id ' in pluck...updated my answer..please check

Comment: its okay ive got it on the code here
$datas = Addrecord::where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->get();